# Javascript page not working when trying to get the ip address of the device opening the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, ip-address, amazon-lex

I am working on `web ui` project based on [this project](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lex-web-ui/tree/master/lex-web-ui). Now what I want to do is that when a user opens the webpage, the `ip address` of the device from which this page is opened should be returned. For this I added the below code to the javascript` code [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lex-web-ui/blob/master/lex-web-ui/src/config/index.js):

```
    function myIP() {
      $.getJSON("//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?", function(data) {
        const ipInformation = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(ipInformation.ip);
        return ipInformation.ip;
      });
    }

const sessionAttr = myIP();
```

I also added `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` at the top of the same `javascript` code file. Now `sessionAttr` constant is called at line 60 of [this code file](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lex-web-ui/blob/master/lex-web-ui/src/store/index.js) (Note that I changed `sessionAttributes: config.lex.sessionAttributes` to `sessionAttributes: config.sessionAttr`).

When I try to load this page nothing shows up. if I do not make changes I described above then the page loads up correctly. So somehow I am making some mistake in my additions which is screwing this page.

**NOTE:** I am not at all familiar with `JavaScript` but based on a quick search I made the changes described above. I understand the issue is in the asynchronous call I am making  and I went through this [suggested link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) but I am unable to figure out the right structure. Can anyone provide me the right syntax so that the page loads up correctly and also returns the `ip address` of the client and sets it to `sessionAttribute`?

**UPDATE:** After some suggestions I made following changes to my code (link here - https://jsfiddle.net/ywdeu0o4/3/)

```
const configDefault = {
  Bot: {
    // initial sessionAttributes
    sessionAttributes: {},
  },
};

$(document).ready(function(){
configDefault.Bot.sessionAttributes.ip = myIP();
 // undefined
});

function myIP() {
    $.getJSON("//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?", function(data) {
        //console.log(data.ip);
        return data.ip;
    });
}
console.log("myVar:",configDefault.Bot.sessionAttributes.ip);
```

When I run this code after opening the console I get `undefined` value for `configDefault.Bot.sessionAttributes.ip`. Why is it coming as undefined and not the ip address?

Comment: `sessionAttr` will be `undefined` because your `myIP()` function doesn't return anything. I'm assuming your issue has to do with returning a value from an asynchronous callback function. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: @MikaelLennholm But why is it not loading the page? Is there error in my code above?

Answer (score 1):

Open the browser dev tool (F12). Very likely you will see an error in the console. For instance the data is already an object, no need to JSON.parse it.

Then there's the asynchronous nature of ajax as Mikael already pointed out. Use a callback function to do something with the data.

EDIT: there was already a link to a page explaining how to use a callback, but maybe it was too much to figure out. You should learn about variables, functions, variable scope, callbacks and async behavior.

Basically you could replace that return with code that updates your global object, and do stuff... or create a new function that you can call back:

```
const configDefault = {
  Bot: {
    // initial sessionAttributes
    sessionAttributes: {},
  },
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  myIP();
});

function myIP() {
  $.getJSON("//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?", function(data) {
    // after succesful ajax response call myCallback with data.ip
    myCallback(data.ip); 
  });
}

function myCallback(theIP) {
// do your stuff here
   console.log("Data.ip:", theIP);
   configDefault.Bot.sessionAttributes.ip = theIP;
   console.log("ConfigDefault:", configDefault);
};
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/bvevqdb1/

You can also call the callback without passing parameters and without (). That would pass the whole ajax result to the callback, and you can then process it there:
https://jsfiddle.net/bvevqdb1/1/

Comment: I am not at all familiar with JavaScript (I just began learning it today) so is it possible if you explain it through code what should be the correct way for my code?

Comment: I am getting error `$ is not defined`. I added the suggested changes to the code at this link - https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lex-web-ui/blob/master/lex-web-ui/src/config/index.js

Comment: I don't see my code anywhere on that page... the jsfiddle examples are working, right?

Comment: Ah, I see now it's a reply to another question your created using my code. Well, a thank you and an upvote for helping out would have been appreciated...

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work fine for me:    https://jsfiddle.net/ywdeu0o4/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  myIP();
});

function myIP() {
    $.getJSON("//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?", function(data) {
        console.log(data.ip);
        return data.ip;
    });
}
```

Comment: Yup, but this is more like what OP asked: https://jsfiddle.net/ywdeu0o4/2/

Comment: When I execute your code above in the editor link you posted I do not see any output(I don't see ip address coming)

Comment: Hit the jsfiddle run button again after opening the console

Comment: did you seriously downvote for that? that isn't "more like" it at all. people are strange

Comment: I didn't downvoted it. One doubt. Don't we need `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to have the jQuery run? in your code I do not see that.

Comment: Since I needed to set the `ip address` to `sessionAttributes` I made some changes to the code you posted but `sessionAttributes` is coming as `undefined` when I open the console and run the example. Here is my updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/ywdeu0o4/3/

Comment: It is undefined because 1. myIP() doesn't return anything. 2. even if it would, it would return it too late. The code that called myIP() will not wait for a return value, because $.getJSON = ajax = asynchronous. The solution is to use a callback, or use js promises/$.deferred but that's way more advanced.

Comment: @yezzz Can you provide the solution that will work? Since I am very new to this so I am unable to figure it out

Comment: Ok, see my answer